# Passing $scope variable from Controller to Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Currently writing a prototype app in Ionic, pretty new to ionic and angular. I've written a small JSON API with about 25 objects in it, I've been able to display the list of them on a page we'll call "Library", I'm trying now to use those list items as links to an individual page for each item we will call a "Lesson". The variable $scope.lessonId is being set properly in the controller but being set as undefined in the service. Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to, or am I just flat out doing this wrong?

```
.controller('LibraryLessonCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, LessonService) {
    $scope.lessonId = $stateParams.libraryId;
    console.log($scope.lessonId);

    LessonService.getLessonId()
       .then(function(response){
       $scope.lesson = response;

       console.log($scope.lesson);
  });
})

.service ('LessonService', function($http){
    return { getLessonId: function() {
        return $http.get('api/postsAPI.json')
            .then(function (response, lessonId) {

                console.log(lessonId);

                for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
                    if(response.data[i].post_id == lessonId){
                        return response.data[i];
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: pass it in method call `LessonService.getLessonId()` AND add parameter in method like `getLessonId: function(lessonId)`

Comment: You are on the right track with separation of logic between Controller and a Service but you should define the boundaries very clearly so you have clear SOS and that means that the service should not know anything about the $scope. Instead extract what is necessary in the controller and have it pass that data to the service in the form of parameter(s) of whatever operations (methods) that can be called. In this case have the controller passe `$scope.lessionId` as a parameter to the service method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass your $scope.lessonId variable to your service call if you like to use the value inside your service.

```
.controller('LibraryLessonCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, LessonService) {
   $scope.lessonId = $stateParams.libraryId;
   console.log($scope.lessonId);

   LessonService.getLessonId($scope.lessonId)
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.lesson = response;
        console.log($scope.lesson);
   });
}).service ('LessonService', function($http){
return { getLessonId: function(lessonId) {
    return $http.get('api/postsAPI.json')
        .then(function (response) {

            console.log(lessonId);

            for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
                if(response.data[i].post_id == lessonId){
                    return response.data[i];
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by passing Id to service and storing it there. Please try not to pass $scope variable to service as it is not a good practice. You can do following:

```
 .service ('LessonService', function($http){
    var lessionId;
    return { 
        /*other methods*/
        setLessionId: function(id) {
            lessionId = id;
        },
        getLessionId: function(){
          return lessionId;
        }

    };
})
```